# Web3.js is not installing correctly with commands "npm install web3", npm install web3 -latest" and npm install ethereal/web3.js -save"

Tags: web3js

```
192-168-1-109:~ connor$ npm install web3@^1.0.0
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for web3@^1.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/connor/.npm/_logs/2018-03-09T07_22_40_901Z-debug.log
192-168-1-109:~ connor$ npm install web3
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar

> websocket@1.0.24 install /Users/connor/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/node_modules/websocket
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
npm WARN connor No description
npm WARN connor No repository field.
npm WARN connor No license field.

+ web3@1.0.0-beta.30
updated 1 package and moved 1 package in 28.16s
```

---

```
192-168-1-109:~ connor$ npm update web3
npm WARN connor No description
npm WARN connor No repository field.
npm WARN connor No license field.

+ web3@1.0.0-beta2
removed 282 packages and updated 1 package in 13.048s
```

---

```
192-168-1-109:~ connor$ npm install ethereum/web3.js -save
npm WARN connor No description
npm WARN connor No repository field.
npm WARN connor No license field.

+ web3@0.20.5
added 5 packages from 7 contributors and updated 1 package in 223.995s
```

I have tried interacting with web3 after every install swell ??

Comment: Maybe running `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` will help, if you're on a windows at least...

Comment: @conwise17 - How did you solve it?

Comment: unistalled, restarted my machine and then re-installed with npm install web3. Was strange how it did not work the first time.